# How to group pages/lists in the left pane Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups

I have a Sharepoint online where I have multiple lists and pages for my different project. There is one list and page per Project and I would like to group them with a "header" in the left pane like in the screenshot.
I am managing to to it by creating a page which is left blank with the list and the other page as sub-folder but I do not like the idea as it consumes one page for nothing.
Do you know a simple way to reach the same without creating an empty page?

[image]

Many thanks and kind regards,
Julien

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood you correctly, but are you using Quick Launch/Navigation for the grouping?

If so, you can simply create a new node using any link you want (even if it is not valid) and group the links by clicking “Make sub link” on the nodes of the lists/pages. No extra empty page needed in this scenario.

References: [Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca) (Section “*Create sub links on the menu*”). /
[Quick Launch Navigation Menu Best Practices.](https://sharepointmaven.com/quick-launch-navigation-menu-best-practices/)

Comment: Thank You Chelsea. I did use Quick launch but what I want to achieve is to have one header which is just a title and completely inactive. Because if I choose a link, even inactive, when somebody from my organisation is clicking on it, it will return a error message and it will look crap.

I really want to have one header inactive. Do you this is possible?

Many thanks, Julien

Comment: @JulienFavre Not possible in Quick Launch does not accept empty headings or nodes (except for the built-in heading “Recent”). But it is possible if you use **Navigation** (with publishing features activated in this site), which allows you to leave the URL field empty when creating a new heading: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/navigation-options-for-sharepoint-online?view=o365-worldwide